# TypeOrm don't synchronize JoinTable

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I am currently working on two schema's. One is created and managed by TypeOrm and the other one is a xenforo instance. I only have query permissions on the xenforo schema. Each user has subscriptions saved on a different table which needs to be joined with the user. This is done through a join table again managed by xenforo so I only have read access to that. So I set up the decorations and everything is working fine. But although the entity is marked as non synchronized TypeOrm tries to create the JoinTable in the xenforo schema which fails because of missing permissions.
This is how my entity class looks like :

```js
@ObjectType()
@Entity({ schema: 'dev_xf', name: 'xf_user', synchronize: false })
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(type => Int)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'user_id', unsigned: true })
  id: number;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column({ name: 'is_moderator' })
  isModerator: boolean;

  @Column({ name: 'is_admin' })
  isAdmin: boolean;

  @Field()
  @Column({ name: 'is_banned' })
  isBanned: boolean;

  @OneToOne(type => UserAuthentication)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  authentication: UserAuthentication;

  @Field(type => [UserUpgrade])
  @ManyToMany(type => UserUpgrade)
  @JoinTable({
    schema: 'dev_xf',
    name: 'xf_user_upgrade_active',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'user_id'
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'user_upgrade_id'
    }
  })
  userUpgrades: Promise<UserUpgrade[]>;
}
```

```js
@ObjectType()
@Entity({ schema: 'dev_xf', name: 'xf_user_upgrade', synchronize: false })
export class UserUpgrade extends BaseEntity {
  @Field(type => Int)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'user_upgrade_id', unsigned: true })
  id: number;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  title: string;
}
```

Is there a workaround to fix the issue that TypeOrm tries to create the JoinTable although both Entities are marked as non synchronized ?

Regards Artur

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Ok, I couldn't find I way to get this work. Seems like the feature needs be implemented: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3443#issuecomment-455479721

Original answer:
If you are using two schemas, you should have two connections in your ormconfig. When you split your entities into different folders (separated by the database), then the migrations are only executed for the entities in that folder.

Example:
Your folder structure should look like:

```
+-- src
    +-- entity
       +-- default
          +-- YourEntity.ts
       +-- external
          +-- User.ts
          +-- UserUpgrade.ts
```

Your ormconfig should look like this (different entities folder)

```
{
    "name": "default",
    "database": "default",
    "type": "mariadb",
    "entities": [
      "src/entity/default/**/*.ts"
    ],
    ...
},
{
    "name": "external",
    "database": "dev_xf",
    "type": "mariadb",
    "entities": [
      "src/entity/external/**/*.ts"
    ],
    ...
}
```

When you now run the migartations for connection YourDatabase, you just run

```
typeorm migration:run -c default
```

and the entities in the external folder will not be touched.

Comment: I am using mariadb. Not sure if database is right though. Because the whole setup works without any issues, so it correctly places the schema name infront of the table it tries to access. The only problem I am having is that it tries to create the JoinTable which fails because it already exists. So ideally I would love to exclude the JoinTable from the automatic synchronization.

Comment: You are right, this doesn't help. I just found a similar issue on Github, seems like synchronize doesnt work for JoinTable and JoinColumn: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3443.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just set up everything as you described I can query the entities without any issues except the cross schema joins seems to be broken. ```node:6016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Entity metadata for App#userUpgrades was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.``` App is one of my default entities.

Comment: Just to get sure, can you (if you not already did) replace 'schema' with 'database' in your entity decorator? I do remember that I once ran into an issue by mixing them up. If you already did, can you post your ormconfig.json?

Comment: Ok, the ormconfig looks good, can you please post your App entity from your default scheme? The error "Entity metadata for * was not found" is almost always based on some minor typo, like in this issue: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/420.

Comment: As they stated I think the reason is that one entity is part of the default connection and the other one of the external. Since the `ormconfig.json` states which entities are included in which connection, this fails. This is are the two files https://pastebin.com/B3Zywh1e

Comment: I’m sorry, TypeORM worked differently from what I expected. I reproduced the scenario and got the same error.
If I have time I will think about it again, but currently I can’t help you out.